# Flutter: Favourites feature with SQLite - Issue with first load

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I have created a details page and using the example from the [Medium](https://medium.com/@suragch/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91) article. I am successfully able to perform CRUD operations.

When I load the DetailsPage, I want to check if the table has the ID and if yes, then make the favourites icon yellow.

```
class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  bool isFav = false;
  MyImpData myData;
  _DetailPageState(this.myData);

  // reference to our single class that manages the database
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget heading = new Container(...),);

    Widget middleSection = new Expanded(...);

    Widget bottomBanner = new Container(...),);

    Widget body = new Column(...);

    final makeBottom = Container(
      height: 55.0,
      child: BottomAppBar(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: buildIcon(),
              onPressed: () {
                _insertOrDelete(myData.id);
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () => share(context, myData),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: Container(...),
      bottomNavigationBar: makeBottom,
    );
  }

  Icon buildIcon() {
    if (isFav) {
      return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.yellow);
    } else {
      return Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white);
    }
  }

  void share(BuildContext context, MyImpData myData) {...}

  void _insert() async {
    // row to insert
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      DatabaseHelper.columnName: myData.name,
      DatabaseHelper.columnDesc: myData.desc,
      DatabaseHelper.columnLoc: myData.location,
      DatabaseHelper.columnId: myData.id
    };
    final id = await dbHelper.insert(row);
    print('inserted row id: $id');
  }

  void _checkFav(String checkId) async {
    final rowsPresent = await dbHelper.queryForFav(checkId);
    if (rowsPresent > 0) {
      print('success');
      isFav = true;
    } else {
      print('Nothing found so inserting you dodo');
      isFav = false;
      //_insert();
    }
    //rowsPresent.forEach((row) => print(row));
  }

  void _insertOrDelete(String id) async {
    final rowsPresent = await dbHelper.queryForFav(id);
    if (rowsPresent > 0) {
      print('Its favourite and removing it');
      _delete();
      isFav = false;
    } else {
      print('Nothing found so inserting you dodo');
      _insert();
      isFav = true;
    }
  }

  void _delete() async {...}
}
```

The DBHelper.dart file has the following for queryForFav(id)

```
//Raw query to check if it is in the favourites
  Future<int> queryForFav(String checkId) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int noOfRows = 0;
    try {
      noOfRows = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery(
          'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE $columnId = ?',
          ['$checkId']));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return noOfRows;
  }
```

My attempt was to create a flag isFav and set it when I get to check the DB. However, that is always false as there is no query executed. Only when I press the button the actual DB query is executed. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to run your queryForFav method in initState() method ? or set the state after you have gotten the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your IconButton(child, buildIcon(), ...) for this class

```
class FavIconWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyImpData myData;

  FavIconWidget(this.myData);

  @override
  _FavIconWidgetState createState() => _FavIconWidgetState();
}

class _FavIconWidgetState extends State<FavIconWidget> {
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  Future<bool> get isFav async {
    final rowsPresent = await dbHelper.queryForFav(widget.myData.id);
    if (rowsPresent > 0) {
      print('Its favourite and removing it');
      await _delete();
      return false;
    } else {
      print('Nothing found so inserting you dodo');
      await _insert();
      return true;
    }
  }

  void _insert() async {

    // row to insert
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      DatabaseHelper.columnName: widget.myData.name,
      DatabaseHelper.columnDesc: widget.myData.desc,
      DatabaseHelper.columnLoc: widget.myData.location,
      DatabaseHelper.columnId: widget.myData.id
    };
    final id = await dbHelper.insert(row);
    print('inserted row id: $id');
  }


  void _delete() async {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: isFav,
        initialData: false,// you can define an initial value while the db returns the real value
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasError) return const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red); //just in case the db return an error
          return IconButton(
            icon: snapshot.data ? const Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.yellow) : 
             Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {})
          );
        });
  }

}
```

basically it wraps the icon with a FutureBuilder, an special widget that awaits for a future value (in this case the return of a DB row), you can give it an initial value while waiting (in this case I gave it a false), but you can ignore it and check if there is a value with snapshot.hasData and return a CircularProgressIndicator to tell the user you're fetching the data

```
return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: isFav,
        initialData: false,// you can define an initial value while the db returns the real value
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasError) return const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red); //just in case the db return an error
          if(snapshot.hasData)
          return IconButton(
            icon: snapshot.data ? const Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.yellow) : 
             Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {})
          );

          return CircularProgressIndicator(); //if there is no initial value and the future is not yet complete
        });
```

I made this StatefulWidget so when you press the button it setState and re-run the isFav future to check again the DB (but it just rebuilds this iconbutton, not your whole page). If you wanted to update your whole page according to that isFav value instead of just the icon then you will have to use that FutureBuilder in all the body of your Scaffold, or at least above in your widget tree where you really need to check that value

Comment: Thanks for this... I was breaking my head over how to get this done... much cleaner as I got all the CRUD out into your class. :). I really need to understand states and future better in flutter.